# Writing a case-insensitive Cypher query to match the beginning of a string in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm having trouble while trying to write a Cypher query that returns all the nodes which their name starts with a certain string. I also need this query to be case insensitive.

Cypher has built in functions for both cases, but I don't know how to combine them

Query for matching the beginning of a string:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.Name STARTS WITH 'Pet' RETURN n
```

Query for case-insensitive strings

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.Name =~ '(?i)ANDR.*' RETURN n
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For a case insensitive comparison using the `STARTS WITH` string comparison operator you can use the `toLower()` string function to convert each side of the comparison to lower case. For example:

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE toLower(n.name) STARTS WITH toLower('Pet') 
RETURN n
```